# Using Export[] sends the file where?

Tags: export

I am trying to use the `Export` command to convert a list of plots into a *.gif file, and the command runs and executes well, but I can't find the file! Where is it supposed to go? Did it even work?

Here is my code :

```
  q[n_, x_] := x (1 + x)^n + x^n;
  points = Table[
     Map[{Re[#], Im[#]} &, 
   Flatten[NSolve[q[n, x] == 0, x][[All]] /. Rule -> (#2 &)]], {n, 1, 20}];

  Export["domniationrootsstargraph.gif", 
    Table[ListPlot[points[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-15, 4}, {-10, 10}}], {i, 1, 20, 1}]
        ]
```

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You can specify the full path. Windows example: `Export["c:\\a.gif", img]`

Comment: I added a few more tricks in the answer, I hope it helps too ;-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Easy to check:

```
Directory[]
```

Which in my case on Win7 gives:

> "C:\Users\vitaliyk\Documents"

You can always specify a complete path to a destination you'd like to save with, for example, top menu **Insert >> FilePath** which will bring a standard browse-directory window:

[image]

This would go instead of your `"domniationrootsstargraph.gif"`. A useful trick to know is command

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

which will allow saving your files by default (without full-path specification) into the directory where your notebook is saved. Also to check files in the `CurrentDirectory` use

```
FileNames[]
```

or, for example,

```
FileNames["*.gif"]
```

for specific file types.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add a slightly different method; something I like to do, since I am fairly OCD about always working in a notebook which is already saved in some directory, is to use NotebookDirectory:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"test.gif",list]
```

This saves your file in the same directory as your .nb file, and is fairly easy to remember in a pinch.

Comment: This only works if the Notebook has first been saved. +1 nevertheless

Comment: As someone who has seen a friend stuggle with and be hurt by severe OCD, I ask you to please refrain from using the word as some bizarre slang for perfectionism. They are not the same at all. Using it that way makes light of a terribly real problem some people face, and promotes misconceptions about OCD. I know you probably didn't mean any harm, but just imagine someone using chronic pain as slang for laziness. It would be insulting and ignorant.

Answer (score 13):

You might try

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "domniationrootsstargraph.gif"], 
   Table[ListPlot[points[[i]], PlotRange -> {{-15, 4}, {-10, 10}}], {i, 1, 20, 1}]]
```

This will let you pick the directory interactively.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this, one I compiled for my thesis writing:**

```
Export2PDF[PlotName_] := 
Module[{A = 600}, 
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", 
StringJoin[{ToString[FileName], ".pdf"}]], PlotName, 
"AllowRasterization" -> True, ImageSize -> 360, 
ImageResolution -> A]]
```

**Plot example:**

```
Plot1 = Plot3D[
Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

**Output**:

[image: 1]

**Export Code:**

```
Export2PDF[Plot1]
```

**Dialog Box:**
[image: 2]

**SAVE and DONE !**

[image: 3]

Comment: You can also right-click the figure and choose Save As... I won't give you quite as much control over the options though.